# Why is there no std::stou?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, std

C++11 added some new string conversion functions:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul

It includes stoi (string to int), stol (string to long), stoll (string to long long), stoul (string to unsigned long), stoull (string to unsigned long long). Notable in its absence is a stou (string to unsigned) function. Is there some reason it is not needed but all of the others are?

related: [No "sto{short, unsigned short}" functions in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895583/no-stoshort-unsigned-short-functions-in-c11)

Comment: Not constructive, for the same reason that the other question is not constructive.

Comment: My question was intended to be more along the lines of "is there some non-obvious drawback of just using stoul". Obviously that will mess with template instantiation, but is there anything else that I'm not considering? Comments on why it was left out would be nice but secondary.

Comment: @NicolBolas I cannot see why this is not constructive. It is a perfectly valid question as I cannot see any reason for this inconsistency and anwers may give insights into some possibly existing valid but not that obvious reason for it.

Comment: @DavidStone on my compiler (and my computer is a typical one), `unsigned long` is the same size and has the same storage capacity as `unsigned int`

Comment: @SethCarnegie Well, what your platform (and maybe the majority of platforms) does is just irrelevant, because an `unsigned long` just is no `unsigned int`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: on my typical computer, `unsigned long` is 64 bits, and `unsigned int` 32. They are different types, and can't be assumed to be the same as each other.

Comment: @ChristianRau: The reason it's not constructive is for the same reason the other question was closed: it would be purely speculative.

Comment: @NicolBolas Like said, the OP (and me) doesn't know it is speculative, as there could just be a perfect valid reason for it burried deep in the language internals of C++. But since you say it's speculative I guess there is no such reason. But again, maybe a C++11-responsible person can still answer it. This is no "Wah wah, where is that damn `stou`"-question, but a question asking for a possibly definite reason for this obvious inconsistency. If you **know** there is no such reason, then well, post it as an answer.

Comment: Oi. Hurry up and close this so I can vote to re-open.

Comment: @Nicol: Aren't the reasoning behind committee decisions accessible to the public? It doesn't seem to me that this question can only have a speculative answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The most pat answer would be that the C library has no corresponding “`strtou`”, and the C++11 string functions are all just thinly veiled wrappers around the C library functions: The `std::sto*` functions mirror `strto*`, and the `std::to_string` functions use `sprintf`.

---

Edit: As KennyTM points out, both `stoi` and `stol` use `strtol` as the underlying conversion function, but it is still mysterious why while there exists `stoul` that uses `strtoul`, there is no corresponding `stou`.

Comment: Do you know why the C++ Committee decided to go for such a C-ish approach? Something like `boost::lexical_cast<>()` seems like a more C++ way of doing things.

Comment: Are these implementation details really standard-defined?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, they are.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Perhaps you could cite chapter and verse. It seems unlikely to me that the standard says "`std::to_string` must be implemented with `sprintf`". 21.5/7 merely states an "as-if" rule for the behaviour of the function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: For `sto*`, C++11 21.5/1: Effects: the first two functions call strtol(str.c_str(), ptr, base), and the last three functions call strtoul(str.c_str(), ptr, base), strtoll(str.c_str(), ptr, base), and strtoull(str.c_str(), ptr, base), respectively.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But you're correct that `to_string` just says "the value of
its argument that would be generated by calling `sprintf`".

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the C++ standard says "must be implemented by calling ...", because the C++ standard still has the global as-if rule: if the standard says `std::sto*` must be implemented as wrappers for the C library functions, and a valid program cannot tell that they aren't secretly implemented differently, the implementation is valid.

Comment: Completely off-topic, I think the practical reasons for not using iostreams like Boost/lexical_cast does is sheer performance; I believe iostreams lose out against strtoul etc. by a considerable margin.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `stoi` exists.

Comment: @KennyTM: Interesting. Actually it says that `stoi` and `stol` both call `strtol`.

Comment: Well, I believe `boost::lexical_cast` is specialized for maximum performance for various types, and thus almost always has better performance than other methods: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Comment: @PaulManta: Simple. `strto...()` and `std::sto...()` (optionally) report the position of the first input character *not* parsed as part of the number. Very useful information if you are parsing potentially malformed input. `boost::lexical_cast<>()` doesn't.

Answer (score 27):

I've no idea why `stoi` exists but not `stou`, but the only difference between `stoul` and a hypothetical `stou` would be a check that the result is in the range of `unsigned`:

```
unsigned stou(std::string const & str, size_t * idx = 0, int base = 10) {
    unsigned long result = std::stoul(str, idx, base);
    if (result > std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("stou");
    }
    return result;
}
```

(Likewise, `stoi` is also similar to `stol`, just with a different range check; but since it already exists, there's no need to worry about exactly how to implement it.)

Comment: The difference between `stoi` and `stol`, or `stol` and `stoll` is also only a range check.

Comment: @Hossein: Between `stoi` and `stol`, yes.  But `stol` and `stoll` do not differ only in range check, they call different library functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long ulval = std::stoul(buf);
unsigned long mask = ~0xffffffffl;
unsigned int uival;
if( (ulval & mask) == 0 )
    uival = (unsigned int)ulval;
else {
    ...range error...
}
```

Using masks to do this with the expected value size in bits expressed in the mask, will make this work for 64-bit longs vs 32-bit ints, but also for 32-bit longs vs 32-bit ints.

In the case of 64-bit longs, ~0xffffffffl will become 0xffffffff00000000 and will thus see if any of the top 32 bits are set.  With 32-bit longs, it ~0xffffffffl becomes 0x00000000 and the mask check will always be zero.

Comment: If `buf` is `"0"`, this will assume a range error occurred.