# How to check conversion from C++ string to unsigned int

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I need to:

1) Find what is the maximum unsigned int value on my current system. I didn't find it on limits.h. Is it safe to write `unsigned int maxUnsInt = 0 - 1;`? I also tried `unsigned int maxUnsInt = MAX_INT * 2 + 1` that returns the correct value but the compiler shows a warning about int overflow operation.

2) Once found, check if a C++ string (that I know it is composed only by digits) exceeded the maximum unsigned int value on my system.

My final objective is to convert the string to a unsigned int using atoi if and only if it is a valid unsigned int. I would prefer to use only the standard library.

Comment: Check out [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Thanks. numeric_limits seems to work but stoi returns an integer or a long, not a unsigned int. And this does not solve my problem: I would like to convert the string if and only if it does not exceed the max unsigned int value.

Comment: Instead of `stoi`, check the "See also" section on the linked page. Also remember that if you want to manually check the string first, then you are making two loops over the string, in essence converting the string to a number twice.

Comment: Haha, people these days seem to miss the answer given on a plate, just because you pointed only at one side of it.

Comment: @Bedo There's `stoul` which returns an `unsigned long`; afterwards, just check against `UINT_MAX`.  Or if you don't like exceptions (and it's quite possible that they aren't appropriate here), just use `strtoul` rather than `atoi`.  Anything which checks for overflow will have to convert anyway, so you might as well use the results of its conversion, rather than wasting your time with `atoui`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a `#define UINT_MAX` in `<limits.h>`; I'd be
very surprised if there wasn't.  Otherwise, it's guaranteed
that:

```
unsigned int u = -1;
```

will result in the maximum value.  In C++, you can also use
`std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`, but until C++11,
that wasn't an integral constant expression (which may or may
not be a problem).

```
unsigned int u = 2 * MAX_INT + 1;
```

is not guaranteed to be anything (on at least one system,
`MAX_INT == UMAX_INT`).

With regards to checking a string, the simplest solution would
be to use `strtoul`, then verify `errno` and the return value:

```
bool
isLegalUInt( std::string const& input )
{
    char const* end;
    errno = 0;
    unsigned long v = strtoul( input.c_str(), &end, 10 );
    return errno == 0 && *end == '\0' && end != input.c_str() && v <= UINT_MAX;
}
```

If you're using C++11, you could also use `std::stoul`, which
throws an `std::out_of_range` exception in case of overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately `strtoul` and `stoul` won't work in cases where his `unsigned int` is not the same size as an `unsigned long` (and unfortunately the absence of `stou` is still an [eternal mystery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8715213/743214)). Still +1, of course, but worth a notice.

Comment: Of course they work.  You just have to assign the results to an `unsigned long`, then bounds check before returning them as an `unsigned`.  With regards to `stoi` etc.: the logical solution would have been to declare a template, and require specializations for all numeric types (including any extended integers the implementation decided to provide), with the semantics "as if" `strtol` or `strtoul` worked on the given type.

Comment: @ChristianRau In fact, did you look at my `isLegalUInt`?  It uses `strtoul` and works.  (BTW: I just edited it to catch a corner case, which IMHO, `strtoul` handles incorrectly.)

Comment: This worked for me. I just had to remove const from char *end. Working with unsigned long to check unsigned int is a very nice idea. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Bedo Whether you need the `const` on `end` depends somewhat on your library.  In C, you can't use it, and if you include `<stdlib.h>`, it's probably wrong.  In C++, if you include `<cstdlib>`, you should definitely need it, but the function should be `std::strtoul` (which is probably what I should have done).  If you include `<stdlib.h>` in C++, I think you're supposed to need it, but it's one of those things I wouldn't count on.

Comment: @JamesKanze I would not teach anybody to include `stdlib.h` in C++…

Answer (score 2):

[`numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) has limits for various numeric types:

```
unsigned int maxUnsInt = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```

[`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) can read a string into any type that supports `operator>>` and tell you whether it failed:

```
std::stringstream ss("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890");

unsigned int value;
ss >> value;

bool successful = !ss.fail();
```

Comment: Alternatively: `bool successful = ss >> value;`

Comment: This is simply incorrect.  First, overflow in pre C++11 was undefined behavior, although all of the implementations I know did it correctly.  And second, even with `"0"`, you'll probably (almost certainly) end up with `successful` false.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) you do not need to calculate it, just use appropriate constant, which it this case should be `UINT_MAX`.

Few notes.

This seems more of a c way in contrast to c++ but since you say you want to use `atol` I stick with it. c++ would be using `numeric_limits` as Joachim suggested. However the c++ standard also defines the c-like macros/definitions, so it should be safe to use.

Also if you want it to be c++-way, it would probably be preferred to use `stringstream` (which is a part of standard c++ library) for conversion.

Lastly I deliberately don't post explicit code solution, 'cause it looks like homework, and you should be good to go from here now.

Comment: There's no reason to use `atoi` if you want error checking (and there's practically never any reason to not what error checking).  The simplest way to check for overflow is to use `strtoul`, and this will return the converted value directly.  (And until C++11, conversions using `istringstream` had undefined behavior in case of overflow, although all of the implementations I know followed the rules of C++11 from the start, and set `failbit` if there was overflow.)

Comment: @James Spare me mate. I just pointed out his error at finding max value, and told a way to do the conversion. I did not want to repeat someone else's answer, and Joachim told about `std::stoi`. I also did not want to give away exact answer at this to be a homework. However, I thought `stringstream` would throw an exception or error in case of over flow. **My bad**, thanks for pointing that out! Then as best pre-c++11 method I would suggest `atol` with manual check if it returned `0`.

Comment: There is practically no case where `atoi` or `atol` would be an acceptable solution.  You have no way of detecting an error from them.  They are only present for historical reasons, and should never be used in modern code.

Comment: Ah, yea i missread it. The value is undefined in case of overflow for `ato?` family. Then I guess it was not possible before c++11, since `stringstream` also went undefined. At least using standard library ('cause you could always write your own input reader). Am I right?

Comment: The problem with the `ato?` family is that they have no way of reporting an error.  When I implemented them (some time in the early 1980's), I did detect overflow, and handled it like `stdtol`, so that is certainly possible, but there's still no way of telling how many characters they processed, and if it was all of them.  As to why `<<` of an `int` was undefined behavior on overflow, you've got me.  I would have expected it to be as it is in C++11 (and as in every C++03 implementation I knew) from the start.