# Checking input is an integer

Tags: c++, int, cin

I am trying to ensure user input is a positive integer and have got my function to work no matter what the user tries to put in.

```
int getNumber()
{
    string userInput;
    int userNumber;
    bool badInput = true;
    cout<<"Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin>>userInput;
    while (badInput)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<userInput.length(); i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(userInput[i]))
            {
                badInput = false;
            }
            else
            {
                badInput = true;
                cout<<"That wasn't a valid input, try again: ";
                cin>>userInput;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    userNumber = atoi(userInput.c_str());
    return userNumber;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this or is this the best way? I tried various other methods such as using cin.bad etc but they always managed to miss some issue.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14893494/1084416) to [How to check conversion from C++ string to unsigned int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14893264/1084416)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check for a positive integer, you probably need
to convert the text to an integer as well.  You should do both
at once; something along the lines of:

```
std::string line;
if ( !std::getline( std::cin, line ) ) {
    //  no input available...
} else {
    std::istringstream parser( line );
    int userNumber;
    if ( parser >> userNumber >> std::ws
            && parser.get() == EOF
            && userNumber > 0 ) {
        //  All OK...
    } else {
        //  Some error in the input.
    }
}
```

It's also possible to use `strtol`, if you have the string from
elsewhere.  Error detection is a bit tricky, because [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)
has some strange semantics in some cases:

```
int
getPositiveInteger( std::string const& input )
{
    char const* end;
    errno = 0;
    long results = strtol( input.c_str(), &end, 10 );
    if ( end != input.c_str() ) {
        while ( isspace( static_cast<unsigned char>( *end) ) ) {
            ++ end;
        }
    }
    return (errno == 0
            && end != input.c_str()
            && *end == '\0'
            && results > 0
            && results <= INT_MAX)
        ? results
        : -1;
}
```

(I've returned -1 in case of an error.)

You'll notice the number of conditions you have to test to be
sure that `stdtol` has worked correctly.

Comment: Why do you `&& userNumber > 0`?

Comment: @MooingDuck Because he said he wanted to check for a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol), something like this:

```
char str[] = "+12345";
char* end;
long number = strtol(str, &end, 10);
if (number < 0) {
    printf("Number is negative!\n");
    // ...
}
if (*end) {
    printf("Junk found after number: '%s'\n", end);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This fails if the string is empty, or contains just white space.  Or if the number if followed by white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::string::find_first_not_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) for testing against digits and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for overflow

```
std::string input;
bool badInput;
int i;

std::cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
do {
    std::cin >> input;
    try {
        badInput = input.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos;
        if (!badInput)
            i = std::stoi(input);
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument&) {
        badInput = true;
    } catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
        badInput = true;
    }

    if (badInput)
        std::cout << "That wasn't a valid input, try again: ";
} while (badInput);
```

This doesn't check for a leading `+`, though.

Comment: Nor does it allow leading or trailing white space.

Comment: @JamesKanze Since it reads from stdin, there is no white space.

Answer (score 0):

Like mvp said, `strol` is the way to go.

```
bool string_to_int(char* s, int* val) {
   char* endptr;
   errno = 0; /* reset errno */
   int i = strtol(s, &endptr, 10);
   if (endptr == s) return false; /* conversion failed */
   if (*endptr) return false; /* unexpected characters behind the integer */
   if (errno) return false; /* out of range */
   *val = i;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to check that the value will fit in an `int` (and his condition that it be positive).  And I'd accept trailing white space; it's usually unintentional (and the user can't see it).