# What are the differences between std::strtol and std::stoi?

Tags: c++, c++11

*Disclaimer: Links are to cppreference.com*

So I have known for a while that [std::atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) has been deprecated and it's been recommended to use [std::strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) instead.

C++11 has introduced [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and I'm trying to understand why one would choose to use it over `std::strtol`.

From what I understand is that stoi calls strtol but throws exceptions.  Also it returns an integer instead of a long.

**Are these the main differences, what am I missing?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there no std::stou?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715213/why-is-there-no-stdstou)

Comment: @KerrekSB That's really an unrelated question...

Comment: @KerrekSB my question is to better understand why to use stoi if ultimately it just calls strtol.

Comment: `std::atoi` has not been deprecated. Deprecation is done in the C++ Standard to indicate that something may be going away in the future. Some people don't approve of `atoi`; that's not deprecation.

Comment: Taken from the [FreeBSD man page of atoi](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/atoi/): `The atoi() function has been deprecated by strtol() and should not be used in new code.`  This may only apply to FreeBSD, but in the portability sense, that would lean me towards not using it in production code.

Comment: @jmstoker The Linux man page for atoi does not mention any deprecation. But since atoi() does not detect errors, I would definitely /not/ use it in production code!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are these the main differences, what am I missing?

The newer, `std::stoi` also works directly from `std::string` (so you don't have to litter your code with `.c_str()` calls) and optionally provides you the first unmatched character as an *index* via a `size_t`, rather than as a pointer.

These changes simplify the usage from within your code.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that stoi provides convenience at the expense of some overhead due to internal casting to convert the string and return an int?

Comment: @jmstoker I suspect you're not going to be getting much overhead, though, as you'd have to do the same conversions if you're using `std::string` as input.

Comment: Right, I'm just wondering if there is more going on in stoi, like the logic providing the exceptions.  I'm probably over analyzing it, but it has me intrigued.

Comment: @jmstoker I suspect the exception logic is more of just a format check on the result of `std::strtol`, since it returns error codes instead of exceptions.  On success, it's likely very low overhead.

Comment: Conversely, if you have string data that is not stored in `std::string` (perhaps it's a memory-mapped text file), then usage of `strtol` is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

One big difference is that `stoi` takes an `std::string` as its argument, so you don't have to tack `.c_str()` onto a string to convert it to an integer.

If you want to convert to a `long`, you can use `stol` instead (and likewise, `stod`, `stof` `stold`, `stoul`, `stoll` to convert to `double,` `float`, `long double`, `unsigned long`, and `long long` respectively).

Answer (score 2):

You'd use `std::stoi()` if you want to pass a `std::basic_string` and you want to get out an `int`. If you prefer to get out a `long` you'd call `std::stol()`.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer stoi() over strtol() since the former throws std::invalid_argument on invalid input. To bad the exception message in GNUs libstdc++ is not to helpfull. E.g.: "what():  stoi"

Answer (score 0):

`std:stoi` is not C compatible and is packed with `<string>` library which has other object oriented implementations that cannot be compiled by a C compiler. Its main use case scenario (should) involves with std:string instead of byte arrays to comply with modern C++ common practice.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, I really wonder why there is not a std::FromString template function taking the type to which you want the string converted as a template parameter. Likewise a ToString template function doing the reverse.

You can easily imagine the implementation using insertion and extraction operators.

```
int i = std::FromString <int> (std::string ("2"))
int j = std::FromString <int> ("2")

std::string = ToString <double> (3.14159)
```

Yes, of course the function names would not have capital letters and they would likely be from_string  and to_string .

Template specialization is possible, of course.
Finally, there really is no restrictions that the types would have to be native types, right?

Comment: True. It "does not answer the question". But creating the two templates is so easy, that I actually think that the resulting codebase will be far more readable and easier to use. (Yes, I have written them. They are truly simple exercises in template functions. Unfortunately, because I wrote them as part of work product, I may not reproduce the code here.)

Comment: I'm not arguing their usefulness. Boost already has `lexical_cast` anyway. I'm just saying your answer doesn't belong here. Maybe it belongs on your blog, or in answer to a question that asked for a third way of converting types, rather that for a comparison of two others that this answer completely ignores.